# How to find given number is twilio buyed number or not

Tags: twilio

How can i find a given number is a twilio valid buyed number number or not
    because client has given me the paid account credential and number but when i used that number api shows a error The 'From' number xxxxxxxxx
    is not a valid phone number or shortcode.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You could use the [Incoming Phone Numbers resource in the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers) to list out the numbers available for the account you have.

To do this in PHP (for example) you could use the following code:

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
require_once('/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library
 
// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "ACxxx"; 
$token = "YYYYY"; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);
 
// Loop over the list of numbers and echo a property for each one
foreach ($client->account->incoming_phone_numbers as $number) {
    echo $number->phone_number;
}
```

There are examples in the documentation in other languages too.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Its not working every time it is showing the same number +15124002048 and i have to send sms using twilio paid number and client  given me "fromnumber" but it throws an exception it is not a valid twilio number for this i have to check is client has buyed a number or not can you suggest me to find from user account also i also have the account credential.

Comment: Hey Varun, this doesn't seem like a Stack Overflow question much any more. Can you drop me an email at philnash@twilio.com with your account SID and we can take a look into this away from here. Cheers